# How to update the array of objects using onChange handler in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below array of objects:

```
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
     {id: 1, key: "key1", value: "value1"},
     {id: 2, key: "key2", value: "value2"}
  ]);
```

And I have the below inputs as well:

```
<TextField name="key" onChange={(e)=> handleTable(e, record.id)} value{rows.filter...}/>

<TextField name="value" onChange={(e)=> handleTable(e, record.id)} value{rows.filter...}/>
```

Now I know that for handling the above inputs I should loop to find the appropriate object based on its ID then try to update it, I need one another for loop for the value of the above inputs as well, but that takes a long time in terms of hooks and reloading each time the user enters something, how can I handle the above situation, both updating and showing the appropriate item in the array?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is any other way of doing this

Comment: from where you're passing `record.id`, also attach the `handleTable` function.

Comment: Can you show the code about the update of `rows` and 'for loop' for value? I think there is a way to merge that. maybe!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to loop the textfields and pass the index to the change handler.

```
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, key: "key1", value: "value1" },
    { id: 2, key: "key2", value: "value2" }
    ]);

   const handleChange = (e,idx) => {
    clone = [...rows];
    let obj = clone[idx];
    obj.value = e.target.value;
    clone[idx] = obj;
    setRows([...clone])
   }
```

and Then you need to loop your rows with text field.

```
 { rows?.map((row, index) => 
     <TextField value={rows[index]?.value} onChange={(e) => 
        handleChange(e,index)} /> 
     )}
```

This may help you to tweak your solution.

Comment: Can we change one from rows' items without using setRows?

Comment: React will only rerender the component if there is any state change. you can use useCallBack,useMemo to avoid from rerendring for performance purpose.

Comment: I'm using Ant Design table which is not headless, hence, I can not loop through my array of objects, however, I realized I'm setting IDs to be start from 1, I made it 0 and now I can get my proper index by simply using rows[record.id], but the way you are updating the rows, IDK if you have actually tried it or not, but when I tend to write in the input, the focus jumps off and again I should refocus the cursor on the input to write the next letter, I'm currently looking for a better and cleaner way to update the rows. btw thanks for your time.

Comment: I'll give it a try to fix the focus out issue. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

```
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
  { id: 1, key: "key1", value: "value1" },
  { id: 2, key: "key2", value: "value2" }
]);

const handleTable = (e, id) => {
  const newRows = [...rows]; //spread the rows array into a new array
  const index = rows.find((item, i) => {
    if (item.id === id) return i;
  }); //found the index using the id

  if (e.target.name === "key") {
    newRows[index].key = e.target.value; // update using the index
  } else {
    newRows[index].value = e.target.value;
  }

  setRows(() => [...newRows]);
};

<TextField name="key" onChange={(e)=> handleTable(e, record.id)} value{rows.filter...}/>

<TextField name="value" onChange={(e)=> handleTable(e, record.id)} value{rows.filter...}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is a better way plz edit

```
const [value , setValue]=useState([])
```

**in html :**

*need separate state for each input elements

```
<input value={value[key] ? value[key] : ""} onChange={(e) => handleSetValue(e.target.value, key)}/>
```

**set value func() :**

```
 function handleSetValue(e, key) {
        setValue(s => {
            const newArr = s.slice();
            newArr[key] = e;

            return newArr;
        });
    }
```